# Crear este XML en C# con XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

Como puedo hacer esto :

```
<Amt>
    <cbc:price>340.00</cbc:price>
</Amt>
```

Este es mi codigo hasta ahora :

```
const string cur = "Ccy=" + @"""EUR";
                writer.WriteStartElement("Amt");
                writer.WriteElementString("InstdAmt", cur, "340.00");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Y este es mi resultado de codigo hasta ahora :

```
<Amt>
  <InstdAmt xmlns="Ccy=&quot;EUR">340.00</InstdAmt>
</Amt>
```

Comment: pero vos estas pasando writer.WriteElementString("InstdAmt", cur, "340.00"); que no tiene nada que ver con lo que queres escribir...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> La sintaxis del XML que quieres obtener es incorrecta, debido a que
>   estas intentando crear el prefijo `cbc` sin su espacio de nombre correspondiente.

Para generar tu documento XML tienes que hacer:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{           
    // default: utf-8
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings)) 
    {               
        writer.WriteStartElement("Amt");

        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "cbc", null, "urn:ejemplo");

        writer.WriteStartElement("cbc", "price", "urn:ejemplo");
        writer.WriteString("340.00");
        writer.WriteEndElement();       
    }

    Console.WriteLine(new UTF8Encoding().GetString(ms.ToArray()));
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkZBeh)

Obtendrás:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Amt xmlns:cbc="urn:ejemplo">
>   <cbc:price>340.00</cbc:price>
> </Amt>
> ```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Clase XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Wikipedia - Espacio de nombres XML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_de_nombres_XML)

Comment: Me ayudo mucho, si no es mucho pedir como podria hacer este 

<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>

Comment: @GianPaulRamírezPacheco, ¿Lo que quieres es que agregue un elemento más a tu XML o es un nuevo documento XML?

Comment: Si quiero agregar uno nuevo como sale arriba

Comment: @GianPaulRamírezPacheco actualicé la demo. Revisa: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkZBeh